# Current sensing on negative 1.1kV DC rail

Tags: high-voltage, negative-voltage, current-sensing, high-side

I searching for a way to do high side current sensing on a -1100V DC rail.

My HV is generated from the hamamatsu C9619 High voltage power supply module and it powers the hamamatsu R647P Photomultiplier tube together with the E849-90 D-type socket assembly also from hamamatsu.

My current region is up to 500 μA.

Any ideas or suggestions would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If your need is only for occasional measurements, it would be easy enough to create a battery-powered wireless milliammeter. For example a shunt resistor, op amp and a microcontroller with some kind of wireless communication (eg. WiFi or Bluetooth).

Another approach would be to make a current sink circuit using a high voltage MOSFET that operates at the -1100V rail. The Hamamatsu C9619 is capable of 2mA current so you have a fair bit to play with. You would have to use (continuous) high voltage rated resistors for the power dropper (and, to be prudent, in series with the high-voltage N-channel transistor drain). A very low power op-amp and a very low Iq shunt regulator for the power would complete the circuit. Recieving it would be a transimpedance amplifier referenced to ground. Pick the series drain resistor to limit the current to a few mA.

For example:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyQ1sP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [hall effect current sensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect#Ferrite_toroid_Hall_effect_current_transducer). 500uA isn't much, but you can use multiple passes through the loop to get a large enough reading.

Another option would be to use an isolated current shunt. You can either do this with a [dedicated device](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau521/slau521.pdf), or simply use a microcontroller, and then pass the signal through an opto-coupler. You'll need an isolated power supply for the microcontroller; or you could just run it on a battery.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: i don't know ,  i send it to zero by upvoting

Answer (score 1):

I have 3 solutions for you:

1 - Replace the power source with one that has **both** voltage and current meters.

2 - Buy a clamp-on DC uampmeter. Make sure you use it in "floating" mode.

3 - Design and build your own DC uampmeter.